# Convert ajax String data to array to update ploty data

Tags: javascript, ajax, playframework, jqplot

I am trying to update a jqplot chart dynamically with Ajax requests.
My server is returning a string represtation of the data as such:

**"[['Juice',30],['Milk',30],['Water',30]]"**

However I need to convert this string into an array of arrays. 
Is this the correct approach to update the data and if so what is the best way to convert the string.

```
   $.ajax({
       url:'http://localhost',
       success:function(plotData){
       var data = plotData.split(","); 
         if(plot){
             plot.series[0].data = data;
             plot.redraw();
         }
       },
       fail:function(error){
          alert('error:'+error);         
       }
   });
```

This code will convert into a one dimentional array:

0: "[['Helpdesk'"
1: "30]"
2: "['Users'"
3: "30]"
4: "['Auto Generated'"
5: "30]]"

Comment: Try `eval("var x= " + plotData)`

Comment: Arun, your suggestion works perfectly. Could you provide it as an answer as opposed to a comment so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval("var x= " + plotData)` as an alternate solution. There are few [dangers in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21)  [using](http://24ways.org/2005/dont-be-eval/) [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil), please go through it before using it.

Comment: -1 for suggesting the use of eval - even the question you linked to says "it's not even necessary to use eval() to parse JSON". It's more or less clear that the "ajax String" in the question is a malformed json response - or can be easily converted to a valid json string and treated appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

for convertiong a string u possibly could use this function

```
var plotData = "[['Juice',30],['Milk',30],['Water',30]]";

function strToArr(str) {
//pattern that checks for '[', ']'
var patt=/[\[\]]/gi; 

//we replace the pattern with '' symbol
var tmp = str.replace(patt,'').split(',');

var result = []
for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i+=2) {
    //now all data is in one array, we have to putt in pairs
    result[i] = [ tmp[i], tmp[i+1] ]
}
return result;
}

console.log( strToArr(plotData) );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Format your data correctly

It looks like the response you're getting from the server is supposed to be JSON. But, it isn't valid json, and as such is represented as a string.

The change required is very trivial, This is invalid json:

```
[['Juice',30],['Milk',30],['Water',30]]
```

This is valid json:

```
[["Juice",30],["Milk",30],["Water",30]]
```

The only difference is the quotes. Changing the response string, may (depending on what you're doing server side) correct things immediately such that `plotData` is already an array of 3 arrays.

### Return the right content type

If you are not already serving the response with correct http headers - ensure the response is served as `application/json`, this of course is in addition to serving a valid JSON string.

### Force interpretation as json

To force jQuery to attempt to parse the response as json - you can set `dataType` explicitly:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    dataType: 'JSON'
    ...
});
```

I can't remember how strict this is  that may work with no server side modifications.

### Use JSON.parse

Alternatively, if you just want to handle the string as-is; you could *just* use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
input = "[['Juice',30],['Milk',30],['Water',30]]";
jsonString = input.replace(/'/g, '"'); // correct quotes as per point 1
result = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

result would then be an array containing 3 arrays.